# How do I increment a column variable in postgres where inputs might change the beginning of the variable?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask

So basically I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE public.portfolio (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('portfolio_id_seq'::regclass),
  name CHARACTER VARYING(80) NOT NULL,
  path CHARACTER VARYING(80) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX portfolio_path_key ON portfolio USING BTREE ("4");
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX portfolio_name_key ON portfolio USING BTREE (name);
```

And I want to be able to input into the path a number followed by a forward or back slash:

`123/456/x`

where `x` is incremented depending on the the two numbers given before it.  I've considered joining two tables together or using sequences but I'm relatively new to postgres and feel like I'm missing something.

What I have now is to use sequences but I'm not entirely sure that's the right way to do it.

If I'm asking the user to put in the first two numbers, how can I get postgres to add it into the database after incrementing the last number or defaulting it to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `SELECT` the row that matches the string by doing something like this:

```
find = "123/456/x".split('/')
find = find.pop() # remove 'x' from the string
find = "/".join(find)
query_str = "SELECT id, path FROM portfolio WHERE path LIKE '%s'" % (find, )
```

Then query the DB with `query_str`, parse `x` from path (using `path.split("/")`) and then issue an `UPDATE` query with the incremented `x` variable. If the `SELECT` query does not return any rows, issue an `INSERT` query to insert the initial value.

Comment: Awesome, this worked like a charm.  Thanks @agentb26!